# Define metric on set and products

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be set.  My question is: if adding point $\ast$ to $X$ to get set $X \cup \{\ast\}$ then on countable product $\prod_{n \in \mathbb N_+} X \cup \{\ast\}$ I found it possible to define metric. For example $d(x,y) = 0 $ if $x=y$ and $d(x,y) = 2^{-n}$ if $n = \min_{y_n \neq x_n} n$ otherwise.

> => Is it possible to define metric $d$ on $\prod_{n \in \mathbb N_+} X \cup \{\ast\}$ with property that $(s)_n = (s_1, \dots, s_n, \ast,
>  \ast, \ast,\dots)$ converges to $(\ast, \ast, \ast, \dots)$?

Here $(s)_n$ denote the sequence $(s_1, \ast, \ast, \dots), (s_1, s_2, \ast, \ast , \dots) , \dots$ where $s_i \in X$.

Other question I have is:

> ==>  Is it possible to define metric on arbitrary set $X$ other than discrete metric?

Also:

> ===> Is it possible to define norm on arbitrary set $X$?

Comment: You can always scale your discrete metric with a positive constant. So on every set, you have uncountable different metrics.

Comment: Is your sequence $(s)_n$ an element of $\prod_{n\geq 1}X\cup\{*\}$? In which case, what do you mean by a single element of a metric space converging to another? It sounds like you might be interested in symbolic dynamics and the shift operator.

Comment: Another metric, which works on all sets is the trivial one: $d(x,x)=0$, $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\ne y$. Again, you can, of course, scale this one, too.

Comment: The answer to your second question is yes. Let $X$ be a set of cardinality $\kappa$. Pick any Hilbert space of cardinality $\geq\kappa$ (for example $\ell^2(\kappa)$). Now choose a set $A$ of $\kappa$ points from this space, so that some sequence of them converges. There is a bijection $f:X\to A$, so you may simply define $d:X\times X\to\mathbb R$ by $d(x,y):=\|f(x)-f(y)\|$. This is then a metric on $X$ and since some sequence converges in this metric, it is not discrete.

Comment: @DejanGovc Thank you! Very good comment! I will try to define $A$ and the bijection $f: X \to A$.

Comment: @DanielRust No I am sorry. I will try to make question clearer. Hope is better now.

Comment: The third question doesn't make any sense. To have a norm, we need to have a vector space structure (over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$)